# Создать Класс: Цвет (модель CMY)

Tags: c#, классы

По заданию нужно Создать 
Класс: Цвет (модель CMY)
Состояние  (поля): `cyan`, `magenta` и `yellow` составляющие (значения  —  вещественные числа из промежутка [0; 1])
Методы конструирования: создание цвета в модели RGB, создание цвета в модели CMY
Свойства: красная, зеленая, синяя, `cyan, magenta, yellow` составляющие
Операции: сложение и вычитание
Примечание: красная, зеленая и синяя составляющие цвета, заданного в модели  `RGB`, и `cyan, magenta, yellow` составляющие этого же цвета в модели `CMY` связаны соотношениями:
`cyan = 1 – red; 
magenta = 1 – green; 
yellow = 1 – blue.`

Мой код

```
using System;

namespace ColorCMY
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow;

        Console.WriteLine("Введите составляющие цвета в модели CMY: ");
        Console.Write("Cyan = ");
        cyan = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Magenta = ");
        magenta = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Yellow = ");
        yellow = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        var color1 = ColorCMY.ColorCMY_FromCMY(cyan, magenta, yellow);
        Console.WriteLine("Цвет cmy ({0}, {1}, {2})", color1.Cyan, color1.Magenta, color1.Yellow);

        Console.WriteLine("Введите составляющие цвета в модели RGB: ");     
        Console.Write("Red = ");
        red = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Green = ");
        green = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Blue = ");
        blue = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        var color2 = ColorCMY.ColorCMY_FromRGB(red, green, blue);
        Console.WriteLine("Цвет cmy ({0}, {1}, {2})", color2.Cyan, color2.Magenta, color2.Yellow);

        var color3 = color1.Add(color2);
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма цветов cmy ({0}, {1}, {2})", color3.Cyan, color3.Magenta, color3.Yellow);

        var color4 = color1.Subtract(color3);
        Console.WriteLine("Разность цветов cmy ({0}, {1}, {2})", color4.Cyan, color4.Magenta, color4.Yellow);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ColorCMY
{
    private ColorCMY(double _cyan, double _magenta, double _yellow)
    {
        Red = 1d - _cyan;
        Green = 1d - _magenta;
        Blue = 1d - _yellow;
        Cyan = _cyan;
        Magenta = _magenta;
        Yellow = _yellow;
    }

    public static ColorCMY ColorCMY_FromCMY(double _cyan, double _magenta, double _yellow)
    {
        return new ColorCMY(_cyan, _magenta, _yellow);
    }

    public static ColorCMY ColorCMY_FromRGB(double _red, double _green, double _blue)
    {
        return new ColorCMY(1d - _red, 1d - _green, 1d - _blue);
    }

    private static double Bound(double value)
    {
        return value < 0 ? 0 : (value > 1 ? 1 : value);
    }

    public ColorCMY Add(ColorCMY secondColor)
    {
        return new ColorCMY(this.Cyan + secondColor.Cyan, this.Magenta + secondColor.Magenta, this.Yellow + secondColor.Yellow);
    }

    public ColorCMY Subtract(ColorCMY secondColor)
    {
        return new ColorCMY(this.Cyan - secondColor.Cyan, this.Magenta - secondColor.Magenta, this.Yellow - secondColor.Yellow);
    }

    public double Red
    {
        get { return red; }
        private set { red = Bound(value); }
    }

    public double Green
    {
        get { return green; }
        private set { green = Bound(value); }
    }

    public double Blue
    {
        get { return blue; }
        private set { blue = Bound(value); }
    }

    public double Cyan
    {
        get { return cyan; }
        private set { cyan = Bound(value); }
    }

    public double Magenta
    {
        get { return magenta; }
        private set { magenta = Bound(value); }
    }

    public double Yellow
    {
        get { return yellow; }
        private set { yellow = Bound(value); }
    }

    private double red;
    private double green;
    private double blue;
    private double cyan;
    private double magenta;
    private double yellow;
}
```

}`введите код здесь`

Не совсем уверена, что правильно реализую сложение и вычитание цветов - не в смысле кода, а в смысле самой модели CMY.

При задании цвета идет проверка вводимого значения, если оно меньше нуля, то округляется до нуля, если больше 1, то округляется до единицы, то же самое применяется к сумме и разности. Это правильно?

Comment: > При задании цвета идет проверка вводимого значения, если оно меньше нуля, то округляется до нуля, если больше 1, то округляется до единицы, то же самое применяется к сумме и разности. Это правильно?

Скорее, это неправильно. Если ваша спецификация требует, чтобы аргумент был в пределах от 0 до 1, то все остальные значения должны интерпретироваться как ошибка. Вы эту ошибку игнорируете.

Comment: Да, про ошибку это скорее правильнее, хотя у меня про обработку ввода неподходящих значений ничего в задании не сказано. Но, допустим, я могу сделать обработку ошибок при вводе значений,  а как быть при сложении и вычитании, когда аргументы могут находиться в промежутке [0, 1], а сумма или разность нет?

Comment: Хм. А какой вообще смысл имеет сложение цветов? По-моему, эта операция не нужна.

Что и вправду пригодится, так это _смешение_ цветов:

    Mix(c1, c2, alpha = 0.5) =
        [R: c1.R * alpha + c2.R * (1 - alpha),
         G: c1.G * alpha + c2.G * (1 - alpha),
         B: c1.B * alpha + c2.B * (1 - alpha)]

Смысл `Mix` — определить, какой цвет получится при наложении с прозрачностью.

Comment: По заданию нужно добавить сложение и вычитание.

Comment: @Heidel: Тогда пусть тот, кто ставит задание, и опишет поведение при переполнении. Операция ни с какой стороны не естественна, так что сделать «естественным образом», «правильно» невозможно без точного определения.

Comment: @VladD ясно, спасибо.